# Wagtail - How to add multiple blogs?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to create multiple blogs on same Wagtail Project. Currently I am using https://pypi.org/project/wagtail-blog/

...and I want the same app in same project for 3-4 times.
Like Blog 1
Blog 2
Blog 3 and so on..

How to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't think this question is well formed enough to get you a good answer. Essentially you will only need one blog app, and to take an argument in the url to direct to different blogs.

Comment: Like @autopoietic said, we probably need a bit more detail.
That being said, you can either deploy the same codebase for each blog, or deploy once and use the multi-site capabilities of Wagtail.
Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any documentation on it and I don't have time to write a full answer, but as pointers, you'll need to create 1 homepage for each blog, and then go to _settings > sites_ to create multiple sites, each pointing to a specific homepage. Then with groups you can restrict users to only be able to post for a specific site.